# Get date from most recent ID with corresponding Boolean-Updated2x

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, merge

I am trying to find the corresponding date of the most recent ID which has corresponding True value

I've utilized df.id.rolling to locate my desired duplicates in my date range window. I just need to identify how far the duplicates are from the most recent occurrence of duplicates.

This is what my starting df looks like

```
df_input:
date        id    duplicate   
1/10/18     1        true         
1/12/18     2        true         
1/20/18     1        false         
1/31/18     1        false
```

This is what i'm trying to get to

```
df_output:
date        id    duplicate   most_recent
1/10/18     1        true         Nan
1/12/18     2        true         Nan
1/20/18     1        false        1/10/18 
1/31/18     1        false        1/10/18
```

Any tips are helpful!

Edited: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Thanks for the tip but this doesn't seem to find the most recent instances only the first instance in a series this returns the first event:

```
         date  id  duplicate most_recent
   0  1/10/18   1       True         NaN
   1  1/12/18   2       True         NaN
   2  1/20/18   1      False     1/10/18
   3  1/31/18   1      False     1/10/18
   4  2/1/18    1      True          Nan
   5  2/8/18    1      False      1/10/18
```

I'm looking for:

```
       date  id  duplicate most_recent
   0  1/10/18   1      True         NaN
   1  1/12/18   2      True         NaN
   2  1/20/18   1      False     1/10/18
   3  1/31/18   1      False     1/10/18
   4  2/1/18    1      True          Nan
   5  2/8/18    1      False     2/1/18
```

Thanks for the help, I don't think I full realized or explain my problem fully. 
Updated ~~~~~

The coded provided works so maybe I should re-post but I need to be able to find the most recent and append a column then I need to be able to find it again based on conditions laid out in an If + For loop statement. See below for the code example

```html
list2 = []

df.loc[~df.duplicates,'most_recent']=df['date'].where(df.duplicates).groupby(df['id']).ffill()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
 
  dup = row['duplicates']
  date = row['date']
  ndate = row['most_recent']
  d1 = date - ndate
  
  if d1 > timedelta(days= 14):
      x= True
      
      if x == True:
          list2.append(x)     
  else:  
      list2.append(dup)
  df.loc[~df.duplicates,'most_recent']=df['date'].where(df.duplicates).groupby(df['id']).ffill()
```

Example ouput:

```
        date  id  duplicate most_recent
  0  1/10/18   1      True         NaN
  1  1/12/18   2      True         NaN
  2  1/20/18   1      False     1/10/18
  3  1/31/18   1      False     1/10/18
  4  2/1/18    1      True          Nan
  5  2/8/18    1      False     2/1/18
```

Some code

```
        date  id  duplicate most_recent
  0  1/10/18   1      True         NaN
  1  1/12/18   2      True         NaN
  2  1/20/18   1      False     1/10/18
  3  1/31/18   1      False     1/10/18
  4  2/1/18    1      True          Nan
  5  2/8/18    1      True      2/1/18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I will do using `ffill`

```
df.loc[~df.duplicate,'most_recent']=df['date'].where(df.duplicate).groupby(df['id']).ffill()
df
Out[740]: 
      date  id  duplicate most_recent
0  1/10/18   1       True         NaN
1  1/12/18   2       True         NaN
2  1/20/18   1      False     1/10/18
3  1/31/18   1      False     1/10/18
```

Comment: Thank you! However, this finds the first event in a series not the most recent, i edited my original post to highlight what I mean

Comment: Thank you, this answered the original question so I hit the checkmark. I'm still struggling with this problem though because I continually need to re group based on my If statement in my for loop. I updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform` function for your code

```
df.loc[df.duplicate,'column_name_you are looking for ']=df.groupby('id').date.transform('first')
```

df

Comment: Thank you but this seems to find the first occurrence not the most recent, see updated post below edits